# How do I make javascript file work on any page that inherit from the master page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am new to asp.net. I have a question, How do I make javascript file work on any page that inherit from the master page? Because i put `<link type="text/javascript" href="scripts/JScript.js" />` in the masterpage and it didn't seem to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem:
Instead of

```
<link type="text/javascript" href="scripts/JScript.js" />
```

use following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/JScript.js"></script>
```

let me know if it does not wok.

Comment: You are right, `link` instead of `script` is at last one of the issues. I haven't noticed this. Nice catch:).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this:

```
<link type="text/javascript" href="/scripts/JScript.js" />
```

**Update**

This seems not to work in your case. Take a look at the second scenario described in this website:

[Calling JavaScript from ASP.NET Master Page and Content Pages - Part II](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=274)

This explains how to do it.

Comment: I forget to mention that I'm trying to run it on server side

Comment: You mean calling java script on server side or just referring to some script to make it run i.e. after page is loaded? Could you explain this?

Comment: Call the javascript on server side sorry

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer and at a link I mentioned there. The second scenario seems to be describing how to make it work in your case.